# The following assembly referenced from Java.Interop.dll could not be loaded System.Runtime 4.0.0.0?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

My project is being in test phase, I've tried it OK on all emulators, debugged OK on one physical device but failed for another physical device with the following message printed in the output window:

```
10-29 09:43:18.376 W/Mono    (16624): The following assembly referenced from Java.Interop.dll could not be loaded:
10-29 09:43:18.376 W/Mono    (16624):      Assembly:   System.Runtime    (assemblyref_index=1)
10-29 09:43:18.376 W/Mono    (16624):      Version:    4.0.0.0
10-29 09:43:18.376 W/Mono    (16624):      Public Key: b03f5f7f11d50a3a
10-29 09:43:18.376 W/Mono    (16624): The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or in the location of the executing assembly (/).
10-29 09:43:18.376 D/Mono    (16624): Failed to load assembly Java.Interop[0x6c0a0040]
10-29 09:43:18.376 W/Mono    (16624): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
10-29 09:43:18.376 E/mono-rt (16624): Stacktrace:
10-29 09:43:18.376 E/mono-rt (16624): 
10-29 09:43:18.376 E/mono-rt (16624): 
10-29 09:43:18.376 E/mono-rt (16624): Attempting native Android stacktrace:
10-29 09:43:18.376 E/mono-rt (16624): 
10-29 09:43:18.385 E/mono-rt (16624):  at ???+0 [0x63ee7667]
10-29 09:43:18.386 E/mono-rt (16624):  at mono_class_get_field_from_name+31 [0x63ee773f]
10-29 09:43:18.387 E/mono-rt (16624):  at ???+31 [0x7355c91b]
10-29 09:43:18.387 E/mono-rt (16624):  at ???+31 [0x7355cb5c]
10-29 09:43:18.387 E/mono-rt (16624):  at Java_mono_android_Runtime_init+2099 [0x7355efbb]
10-29 09:43:18.387 E/mono-rt (16624):  at ???+2099 [0x64783962]
10-29 09:43:18.388 E/mono-rt (16624): 
10-29 09:43:18.388 E/mono-rt (16624): =================================================================
10-29 09:43:18.388 E/mono-rt (16624): Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
10-29 09:43:18.388 E/mono-rt (16624): a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
10-29 09:43:18.388 E/mono-rt (16624): used by your application.
10-29 09:43:18.388 E/mono-rt (16624): =================================================================
```

The issue is surely not in my code (the execution does not have any chance to jump in anywhere in my code and the code works fine in another physical device running Kitkat 4.4). The device I'm testing on runs Lollipop 5.0 (so the API should surely support what Kitkat supports).

I've not tried creating a signed APK and installing that final build on the device but debugging should be done first. I'm also not sure if this relates to some problem of failed ADB interface driver? (although the device seems to be connected OK and its name shows up in Visual Studio).

I've tried Googling around for this issue but found nothing (with just a few result). According to the message, looks like this `System.Runtime` should be referenced? (strangely that it's not referenced in my project but it still runs fine in all emulators and one physical device, also the building is always successful). I've tried finding that assembly to add as reference in my project but also not found any suitable (from the Reference manager window).

The device I'm testing on may be chosen as the running device for our clients.

### Update

I've tried digging more a little and can be sure that the ADB interface driver works correctly (some apps can be built and debugged OK). However it's very very very strange that even the ***Hello world*** app (auto-generated when creating a new blank Android project in Visual Studio) cannot be debugged OK (with the same exception as I posted above). So it's obviously something wrong with Xamarin Android here.

Comment: What version of Xamarin Studio/Visual Studio Xamarin Plugin? I would first try adding the **Java.Interop** and **System.Runtime** references to your Android project and then delete all `/obj/` and `/bin/` folders from your Android and PCL project directories and rebuild. The **Java.Interop** reference is located at: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Java.Interop.dll` and the **System.Runtime** reference is located at: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.dll`

Comment: The Xamarin Visual studio version is 4.1 and Monoandroid version is 6.0 - I've tried adding reference as you suggested but the `System.Runtime` cannot be added (there is a warning yellow mark on it), not any helpful message I could find.

Comment: @hvaughan3 there is not anything to do with referencing assemblies  manually here, everything should be fine as usual. The problem involves ***Use Fast Deployment***, that option unfortunately does not work for my device, it causes the missing assembly issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's very lucky for me that the app debugged OK via my device has the option ***Use Fast Deployment*** unticked (so I just tried unticking this in my current project and it worked):

[image]

Looks like fast deploying option makes the building process link references  incorrectly (so causing some referenced assemblies missed for no clear reason).

That option does not work for my device may be partially because of the ADB interface driver. This driver is not an offical driver from the device manufacturer, it's some kind of general ADB interface driver for all android devices (and it's unsigned, I had to disable Driver Signature Enforcement to be able to install that general driver (so that I can debug on my device).

I think this answer would be very helpful for those encountering the same situation :)